# Weird colors on Chrome/Linux

Tags: google-chrome, colors

I'm experiencing a weird issue on Chrome 61 on Linux,

Colors on chrome are very different compared to others browsers:

[image]
On the left this is Firefox, on the right Chrome

As you see, Chrome colors are not enough saturated.

The chrome internal color picker show the expected Hex value, but any other external color pickers indicates this is not the good red and yellow.

I've reset my chrome settings and removed all extensions, but this not solved my issue.

Did someone have experienced the same issue?

Thanks

Comment: It's ok now. It was a color profile issue on one of my monitor. I just deleted all my color profiles and logout/login. Firefow and chrome display exactly the same colors now :)

Answer (score 72):

I had this problem as well, I solved it like this:

1. Access: **chrome://flags**
2. Change flag: **Force color profile** to **sRGB**

Comment: seems fix my problem:  ubuntu 14 + chrome 61

Comment: Fixed my issue on arch + gnome + Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 on an external display

Comment: adding this condition - change flag Force color profile to sRGB

Comment: fixed it on chrome 62 ubuntu 16.04 using
Force color profile sRGB

Comment: Fixed for my linux mint!

Comment: Setting chrome://flags/#force-color-profile to sRGB works on Chromium v73.0.3683.86 for Ubuntu v18.10. My WebGL colors were slightly incorrect in Chromium but correct in Firefox. I verified by drawing green (0x00ff00ff) in the shader and comparing Firefox and Chromium outputs in Gimp.

Comment: You are my savior.

Comment: Ok for Xfce Desktop on Ubuntu 20.04!

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, but I've realized this is a problem with Chromium & Electron based applications picking the wrong color profile. While all solutions mentioned here solve the problem for Chrome, the solution I've found fixes it for all Chromium/Electron based applications, such as VSCode & Discord.

Go to this Google Docs document and follow the 5 steps under "Using colormgr from the command line". This fixed the issue on all Chromium-based applications by setting sRGB as the default color profile.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jMokB_OBkZVELu22li8vnHxAUoL1eGnLedP-1Gttv40/edit#heading=h.z8rbug83238e