# Strange boxes on Chrome/Linux

Tags: google-chrome, artifacts

I'm experiencing weird artifacts on Google Chrome 61 on Linux.

There are some strange boxes rendered on many pages:

Example 1:

[image]

Example 2:

[image]

Note: I changed the background color of the body `#444954` to make the boxe more visible, you can try by yourself on this page with the chrome devtools: https://bitbucket.org/account/signin/. 
You should see a single color on the whole background.

These boxes are not DOM elements and are often visible on large colored backgrounds. Usually It seems to surround elements of the page (very visible on the screenshot) and are always at the same place on a single page. So I think the position of the boxes are directly related to the content.

This is not a monitor issue, I've 3 different monitors and boxes are visible on all screens.

What I've tried:

- Remove chrome extensions
- Reset chrome settings
- Installed prior Nvidia drivers.

Didn't changes anything.

I do not know if it's related, but I've another unresolved issue with Chrome Colors: [Weird colors on Chrome/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199758/weird-colors-on-chrome-linux)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Ok i've checked "Use hardware acceleration when available" from the Chrome settings, and boxes no long appears. Don't really know why, but it works. Solved

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, try to add the style rule on the background layer:

```
backface-visibility: hidden;
```