# Chrome color issue

Tags: linux, google-chrome, colors, chromium

After upgrading the Chrome-family browsers (to 61.x), I faced this issue. The background color on the Chrome gangs was always same with Firefox (for years), but now it is more shiny (became matt on screenshots, its original link is [here](//evarkadasi.biz)). The issue is also same with link (<a>) colors and other colored elements.

[image: chrome-color]

Here are some issue related stuff;

Hex code of background color: `#f9e514`

Right side browsers (from behind): Firefox, Epiphany Web Browser, Ubuntu Web Browser, Midori
Left side browsers (from behind): Google Chrome, Chromium, Opera

Browser Infos;

**Firefox**: 56.0, Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0
**Epiphany**: 3.18.11, Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/604.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Safari/604.1 Ubuntu/16.04 (3.18.11-0ubuntu1) Epiphany/3.18.11
**Ubuntu Web Browser**: -
**Midori**: 0.5.11, Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux) AppleWebKit/538.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/538.15 Midori/0.5

**Google Chrome**: 61.0.3163.100, Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
**Chromium**: 61.0.3163.79, Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/61.0.3163.79 Chrome/61.0.3163.79 Safari/537.36
**Opera**: 48.0.2685.32, Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.91 Safari/537.36 OPR/48.0.2685.32

So, what happened with 61.x version all these browsers?

Comment: This seemed like it could be a question for Stack Overflow. But at the end, you asked *"what happened with 61.x version all these browsers?"* You should probably take that question to another site, like [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/). Do you have a programming and/or development question you could ask instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weird colors on Chrome/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199758/weird-colors-on-chrome-linux)